# SQL find and delete repeated items

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I am using PostgresSQL. I have following structure of my gps points table:

[image]

As you can see points with `id = 551071` and `551073` and `551075` have the same coordinates. I want to delete them, all that 3 points. But the problem is that I have a dataset of 600K objects and I want to delete all such repeated coordinates for all users. This means that I want to delete that three points from user `10`. If user `11` also has the same coordinates, then no need to delete. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `exists` operator applied on an aggregate subquery:

```
DELETE FROM my_table a
WHERE  EXISTS  (SELECT   b.lon, b.lat, b.user_id
                FROM     my_table b
                WHERE    a.lon = b.lon AND
                         a.lat = b.lat AND
                         a.user_id = b.user_id
                GROUP BY b.lon, b.lat, b.user_id
                HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```